# If I extend a class in python, how to automatically return the result as the new class?

Tags: python, pandas, class, oop, object

Here is a simple example:

```
import pandas as pd

class test_pd(pd.DataFrame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


    def my_copy(self):
        return self.copy()



if __name__=='__main__':
    a = test_pd() #a has a.my_copy()
    b = a.my_copy() #b does not have b.my_copy()
```

I would like the `test_pd.my_copy()` function to return a `test_pd` class whenever I called `copy()` function which is from pandas. Technically, I can always use something like `return test_pd(self.copy())`. But I hope there could be a smarter solution so I don't have to make this modification every time I want to call a similar pandas function.

PS: I understand that `DataFrame.copy()` returns a `DataFrame` object, but I am just wondering, since my own class extends the `DataFrame` class, whether it is possible my object also extends a `DataFrame` Object automatically, so whenever the `DataFrame` function returns a `DataFrame` object, it will return a `test_pd` object when called in `test_pd` class.

Comment: No, you need to be explicit about what that method should return.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the class instance, and then use the `cls` function as a constructor, so:

```
def my_copy(self):
    return type(self)(self.copy())
```

So here `type(self)` will be `test_pd`, but if you further subclass it, `type(self)` will be a `sub_test_pd`, and thus you will call that constructor.

Of course in case you change the `__init__` at some level, you will have to update your `my_copy` as well, since then the parameters will no longer fit.

Note that for the above reason, and other reasons, this tends to be an anti-pattern. Yes it is technically possible, and yes, it can be beneficial. But it sometimes can fail quite dramatically.